# How to set state of a nested array in React (Edited)

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I have this set of data

`this.state = {
    weeks: [
        {
            weekNumber: 1,
            weights: []
        },
        {
            weekNumber: 2,
            weights: []
        }
    ]
}`

What I want to do is create a new array and set it to 'weights'. I've checked other posts like this one:
[Set state of nested array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51433182/set-state-of-nested-array)

I assume I do something similar.

Edit: Also, say for instance I want to update each individual week's weights array, how would I go about doing that?

Comment: Are you trying to create a new entry in state called "weights" or create a variable called "weights"?

Comment: @CodySwann I figured I would create a new array variable and use that new array variable to update the state 'weights'

Comment: @Bpicks - take a look at react's immutability helpers—specifically, the update method. You can create a new state object and then use setState to update your entire state with the updated state. https://reactjs.org/docs/update.html

Comment: @heyitsjhu beat me to it. That's the best way. Otherwise, you have to do some nasty object extensions with the spread operator

Comment: @CodySwann `@heyitsjhu Ok, say for instance I want to update both weeks' weights' arrays. Would I just map through each week and update the state using the update method from immutability helpers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I usually use this solution:

```
const newWeeks = [ ...this.state.weeks ];
newWeeks[0] = { ...newWeeks[0] };
//modify `newWeeks`

this.setState({
  weeks: newWeeks
});
```

---

**Update 1:**
Live version: https://codesandbox.io/s/20v7r2zx0j?fontsize=14&module=%2Fsrc%2FTest.js

---

**Update 2:** thank @bird. Problem is **Spread** only goes one level deep when copying an array(or object), so we need an extra step here:

```
newWeeks[0] = { ...newWeeks[0] };
```

Comment: This is not the way to clone a nested object. The weight property still a reference. Modified the  `newWeeks[0].weight`  cause change to `this.state.weeks[0].weight` also.

Comment: Hi, you can see I created new array from old array using **Spread syntax**, It create new array with value, not reference, read more about it here > https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax

Comment: Just put  `console.log(this.state.weeks);` at line 21 in your code sandbox, right after the `newWeeks[0].weights = [1, 2, 3];` line. You will see the `weeks[0].weights` also modified, when `setState` action doesn't run yet.

Answer (score 0):

Because it's a nested object, then you can clone with native javascript code with `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj))`

```
this.state = {
    weeks: [
        {
            weekNumber: 1,
            weights: []
        },
        {
            weekNumber: 2,
            weights: []
        }
    ]
}

const newWeeks = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.state.weeks))

newWeeks[0].weights = [1,2,3]

this.setState({weeks: newWeeks})
```

The other normal clone like: `[...this.state.weeks]` or `Object.assign([], this.state.weeks)` only clone properties of level 1 not the nested, in your case, the `weight` property will not be cloned, just copied the reference in a normal way.

You can take a look at [cloneDeep](https://lodash.com/docs/#cloneDeep) of `lodash` lib or use [immer](https://github.com/mweststrate/immer) to archive your goal, also.